# ERROR:Additional information: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: W. Path '', line 2, position 1

Tags: c#, php, json, datagridview

> An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException'
>   occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: Unexpected character encountered while parsing
>   value: W. Path '', line 2, position 1.

This was a problem for me, since I was using an application (developed in C#). The way I found to get the information was: create some PHP files that, hosted on my server, will connect locally to the database and return the information in JSON format. Then I would need to change my C# application for consuming those JSON. In c# Displaying JSON from PHP into a DataGridView using Json.NET

**Coding:**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.IO;

using System.Net;

using System.Text;

using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace HTTTPRESPONSE

{

class User

{

    [JsonProperty("userid")]
    public string userid { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("password")]
    public string password { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("first_anme")]
    public string first_name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("last_name")]
    public string last_name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("role")]
    public string role { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("active")]
    public string active { get; set; }

}
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        var data = wc.DownloadString("http://***.**.***.***/data.php");
        List<User> users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(data);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = users;
      }
   }
 }
```

**Error in the line:**

```
List<User> users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(data);
```

My Reference is : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/609027/Displaying-JSON-from-PHP-into-a-DataGridView-using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(stream);
            String json = streamreader.ReadToEnd();
            List<User> users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(json);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = users;
```